# Pointers to consecutive elements in an array of structs not at uniform offsets?

Tags: c, pointers, structure, pointer-arithmetic

This is kind of repeated question but could not find the proper explanation anywhere.

I have the below code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct student_data_boys
{
    int roll_b;
    char name_b[4];
} student_data_boys;

int main()
{
    student_data_boys *ptr;
    int i;
    int num = 5;
    ptr = (student_data_boys *) malloc(num * sizeof(student_data_boys));
    if(ptr == NULL) 
        printf("Can't allocate memory.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("Allocated memory space size is : %ld bytes.\n",
         (num * sizeof(student_data_boys)));
    for(i=0;i<num;i++) {
        printf("Start address of data1[%d] is : %p.\n", i+1, ptr+i);
    }
    free(ptr);
}
```

When I increment the structure pointer the expected next address is base address plus the size of the structure block (which is 8 here), but when I see the output the next size is not as expected.

The outputs is as follows:

```
Allocated memory space is : 40.
Start address of data1[1] is : 0x55f5097c1010.
Start address of data1[2] is : 0x55f5097c1018.
Start address of data1[3] is : 0x55f5097c1020.
Start address of data1[4] is : 0x55f5097c1028.
Start address of data1[5] is : 0x55f5097c1030.
```

Can someone explain this behavior?

Comment: Between 18 and 20 there are 8 bytes, it's base 16 hex, not base 10.

Comment: OT: But well, *if* doing C, then just drop those useless casts.

Comment: Ohhh...yeah. My interpretation was wrong as i was ignoring the base hex and considering it as base 10.

Comment: OT: Why do only boys have student data?

Comment: Hahahaha....The code had data for boys as well as girls...But for my query i omitted the rest part of the code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The addresses you're seeing match your expectations, and they are indeed 8 bytes apart. It's just that `%p` in printf format strings results in hexadecimal notation (as you can tell from the `0x` prefix). Thus, for example, `0x55f5097c1020 - 0x55f5097c1018 == 8`.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying... I was ignoring the base hex part.

Comment: @Raja: Note that if an answer to a question is satisfactory, you should mark it as accepted. If you do so, there's no need for the comment, the acceptance says exactly what your comment says. Welcome to StackExchange.